# How to create an SSL connection using the Smack XMPP library?

Tags: java, ssl, xmpp

I'm building a small program that acts as an XMPP client and I am using the [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) library. Now, the server I am connecting to requires SSL (in Pidgin I have to check "Force old (port 5223) SSL"). I'm having trouble getting Smack to connect to this server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at this thread.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/thread/37678

Essentially, you need to add these two lines to your code:

```
connConfig.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
connConfig.setSocketFactory(new DummySSLSocketFactory());
```

where connConfig is your ConnectionConfiguration object. Get the DummySSLSocketFactory from the Spark source code repository. All it does is accept virtually any certificate. This seemed to work for me. Good luck!

Comment: This DummySSLSocketFactory allows any certificate past, even if it's expired or not singed by a root CA. So I suggest the approach of getting the CA Certificate and storing it in KeyStore and adding it in the application and using the same. Please refer the answer by me for more details.

Comment: IOException: Unconnected sockets not implemented

smack 4.2.3

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by the following:

**Storing the CA Certificate in Keystore**

To store the certificate in a Keystore follow these steps.

**Step 1:** Download the bouncycastle JAR file. It can be downloaded from the here: Bouncy Castle JAVA Releases

**Step 2:** Use the following command to store the certificate in keystore

> ```
> keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "<certificate_file_with_path>" -alias "<some_name_for_certificate>" -keystore "<file_name_for_the_output_keystore>" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "<bouncy_castle_jar_file_with_path>" -storetype BKS -storepass "<password_for_the_keystore>"
> ```

**Step 3:** Verify the keystore file

> ```
> keytool -importcert -v -list -keystore "<file_name_for_the_keystore_with_path>" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "<bouncy_castle_jar_file_with_path>" -storetype BKS -storepass "<password_for_the_keystore>"
> ```

This shall list us the certificate included in the keystore.

We have a keystore which we can use in our code.

**Using the keystore**

After generating this keystore, save it in the raw folder of your application. The use the below code to get the certificate handshake with the openfire server.

To create a connection with openfire using XMPP, you may need to get the config. For the same, use the below method:

> ```
> public ConnectionConfiguration getConfigForXMPPCon(Context context) {
>         ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(URLConstants.XMPP_HOST, URLConstants.XMPP_PORT);
>         config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
>         config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
>         config.setCompressionEnabled(false);
>         SSLContext sslContext = null;
>         try {
>             sslContext = createSSLContext(context);
>         } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (CertificateException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>
>         config.setCustomSSLContext(sslContext);
>         config.setSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
>
>         return config;
>  }
>
> private SSLContext createSSLContext(Context context) throws KeyStoreException,
>             NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, IOException, CertificateException {
>         KeyStore trustStore;
>         InputStream in = null;
>         trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
>
>         if (StringConstants.DEV_SERVER_IP.equals(URLConstants.XMPP_HOST) || StringConstants.TEST_SERVER_IP.equals(URLConstants.XMPP_HOST))
>             in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ssl_keystore_dev_test);
>         else if(StringConstants.STAGE_SERVER_IP.equals(URLConstants.XMPP_HOST) || StringConstants.STAGE2_SERVER_IP.equals(URLConstants.XMPP_HOST))
>             in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ssl_keystore_stage);
>         else if(StringConstants.PROD_SERVER_IP.equals(URLConstants.XMPP_HOST) || StringConstants.PROD1_SERVER_IP.equals(URLConstants.XMPP_HOST))
>             in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ssl_keystore_prod);
>
>         trustStore.load(in, "<keystore_password>".toCharArray());
>
>         TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
>                 .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
>         trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
>         SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
>         sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(),
>                 new SecureRandom());
>         return sslContext;
> }
> ```

All done..!! Just connect.. Now your connection is secured.

All follow the same in my blog at [smackssl.blogspot.in](http://smackssl.blogspot.in/2015/10/ssl-implementation-in-android-for-smack.html)

Comment: What are the `Context` and `R` classes?

Comment: @Alastair `Context` is the application or class level context, which you can pass using `this`. And `R` is a class from which I get the key stores stored in my hard drive in the raw directory, you can directly pass that resource to the in by any other means as you like too.

Comment: Sounds like you're working in a specific framework. Android? I'm not, so this just confused me for a bit. But I figured it out. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the code is domain specific, but you can apply the same to any domain. Small changes required. Hope you felt the answer helpful, upvote shall be appreciated. ;-) Thanks.

Comment: @Iqbal, will this cetificate ask persmission from the user to allow ?

Comment: @Priya In Android all the permissions are asked when the user installs the application, so we do not ask any permission for the user. If you are working on a different framework, or even in Android if you want to ask the permission from the user, then you can do it before loading the trust store, using a confirm box, to ask user wants to continue by loading it or no.. Hope this helps!!

Comment: thank u Iqbal.., what does <certificate_file_with_path> meant her ?

Comment: @Priya it is the local path of your certificate with full name.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's quite easy to achieve. Take a look at the [ConnectionConfiguration](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration.html) class, and in particular the setSecurityMode method which accepts a ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode enum as a parameter. Setting this to "required" forces Smack to use TLS.

from the Javadoc:

> Securirty via TLS encryption is
>   required in order to connect. If the
>   server does not offer TLS or if the
>   TLS negotiaton fails, the connection
>   to the server will fail.