# In Memorizing Trust Manager in Xmpp Connection using Smack api, How to avoid to askin permision from client in android?

Tags: android, openfire, smack

Here am using Openfire server to chat application using Smack api. while establishing connection between the client and server its asking certificate so i used Memorizing trust manager like,

```
SSLContext sslContext = null;
try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null,MemorizingTrustManager.getInstanceList(getApplicationContext()), new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setCustomSSLContext(sslContext);
```

But the problem is MemorizingTrustManager showing popup to get permission from user like

[image]

Is there any way to handle this..If any one knows please post your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get the question: Showing this dialog when the service's certificate could not be verified by the system (e.g. via the installed CAs) is exactly what MTM is supposed to do.

Comment: @Flow, Can I able to accept in background... what i need, is i don`t want to show this popup to user, or is there any other way to provide certificate rather than MTM.

Comment: Hope my answer here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33148123/4629102 and also my blog: http://smackssl.blogspot.in/2015/10/ssl-implementation-in-android-for-smack.html

Answer (score 0):

If you look into source of `memorizingTrustManager`, You will observer it is handling two truststores. One is system default trust store, one is application trust store. The permission you were asked means, that certificate could not be verified in any of the store. So one way and appropriate way is to load that certificate in your app trust store. In this way, during `ssl handshake`, trust store will check internally and accepts the certificate from server.

```
/** Creates an instance of the MemorizingTrustManager class that falls back to a custom TrustManager.
 *
 * You need to supply the application context. This has to be one of:
 *    - Application
 *    - Activity
 *    - Service
 *
 * The context is used for file management, to display the dialog /
 * notification and for obtaining translated strings.
 *
 * @param m Context for the application.
 * @param defaultTrustManager Delegate trust management to this TM. If null, the user must accept every certificate.
 */

public MemorizingTrustManager(Context m, X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager) {
    init(m);
    this.appTrustManager = getTrustManager(appKeyStore);
    this.defaultTrustManager = defaultTrustManager;
}
```

Check the source here [MemorizingTrustManager](https://github.com/ge0rg/MemorizingTrustManager/blob/master/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MemorizingTrustManager.java)

so don't pass null, provide a trustmanager which have your server certificate.